# If the original Github project is deleted, does your copy get deleted also?

Tags: github

For clarification I am talking about watching it, starring it, and forking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fork won't be deleted unless it's a private repository.
See https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/

Comment: If it was a private repository I'd have to be invited, correct? Do you think forking a project with no intention to do something with it just to have it there in case it gets deleted looks bad on your profile?

Comment: There will be a PRIVATE tag beside the repo name, or you can try access it while logged out/incognito mode. It's very common to fork a project without doing work on it.